# Batch listener for pubsub with spring integration

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use pubsub subscription. I managed to connect to subscription and get messages using google documentation. Unfortunately handling messages is slow and it would be much faster if I could get messages in batches. Here is my working code that can process one message at time:

```
@Bean
fun inputMessageChannel(): MessageChannel {
    return PublishSubscribeChannel()
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "inputMessageChannel")
fun inboundChannelAdapter(
    pubSubTemplate: PubSubTemplate
): MessageSource<Any> {
    val messageSource = PubSubMessageSource(pubSubTemplate, pubSubConfig.subscription)
    messageSource.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL)
    return messageSource
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputMessageChannel")
fun messageReceiver(
    message: Message<ByteArray>
) {
    try {
        handleMessage(message.payload)
        message.headers.get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE, BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage::class.java)?.ack()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        log.error(e) { "Failed to handle message: ${message.payload}" }
    }
}
```

I tried changing messageReceiver function to work with list of messages like that:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputMessageChannel")
fun messageReceiver(
    messages: List<Message<ByteArray>>
) {
    try {
        handleBatchMessages(messages)
        messages.forEach {
            it.headers.get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE, BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage::class.java)?.ack()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        log.error(e) { "Failed to handle messages." }
    }
}
```

but i get

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@7cd56906], failedMessage=GenericMessage [...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to class org.springframework.messaging.Message (java.lang.Byte is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.messaging.Message is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

How can i process list of messages instead of single message at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PubSubMessageSource` does not produce batches. It fetches them indeed, but then it emits cached messages one by one:

```
  protected Object doReceive(int fetchSize) {
    if (this.cachedMessages.isEmpty()) {
      Integer maxMessages = (fetchSize > 0) ? fetchSize : 1;

      List<? extends ConvertedAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage<?>> messages =
          this.pubSubSubscriberOperations.pullAndConvert(
              this.subscriptionName, maxMessages, !this.blockOnPull, this.payloadType);
      if (messages.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
      } else if (messages.size() == 1) {
        // don't bother storing.
        return processMessage(messages.get(0));
      } else {
        this.cachedMessages.addAll(messages);
      }
    }

    return processMessage(this.cachedMessages.pollFirst());
  }
```

I don't see any batch producing support in those Spring Integration channel adapters for Pub/Sub: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/main/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spring/pubsub/integration/inbound

Comment: This is correct answer. By using this library it is impossible to achieve what i wanted to do.
I had to change my approach. I went with this:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#unary_pull_code_samples